# dyld[23795]: Library not loaded. no such file

Tags: c, cs50

I've tried so many ways but getting same error again and again

```
./hello
dyld[23795]: Library not loaded: libcs50-11.0.2.dylib
  Referenced from: <1557102E-E26E-34DF-B9C3-36303379546A> /Users/ritamdebnath/Downloads/codes/hello
  Reason: tried: '/path/to/library/libcs50-11.0.2.dylib' (no such file), '/path/to/library/libcs50-11.0.2.dylib' (no such file), '/path/to/library/libcs50-11.0.2.dylib' (no such file), '/path/to/libcs50-11.0.2.dylib' (no such file), '/libcs50-11.0.2.dylib' (no such file), 'libcs50-11.0.2.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OSlibcs50-11.0.2.dylib' (no such file), 'libcs50-11.0.2.dylib' (no such file), '/path/to/library/libcs50-11.0.2.dylib' (no such file), '/path/to/library/libcs50-11.0.2.dylib' (no such file), '/path/to/library/libcs50-11.0.2.dylib' (no such file), '/path/to/libcs50-11.0.2.dylib' (no such file), '/libcs50-11.0.2.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/ritamdebnath/Downloads/codes/libcs50-11.0.2.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Users/ritamdebnath/Downloads/codes/libcs50-11.0.2.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/ritamdebnath/Downloads/codes/libcs50-11.0.2.dylib' (no such file)
zsh: abort      ./hello
```

I've tried these commands but getting same error again and again.
Here are the commands --

```
find / -name "libcs50-11.0.2.dylib" 2>/dev/null
```

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/path/to/library:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: Instructions saying `/path/to/library` should not be taken literally, but be replaced by the *actual* path to where that file is stored.

Comment: Didn't get it what you tried to say

Comment: Tried to say that the export should not contain "/path/to/library" but "/Users/ritamdebnath/Downloads/dyld", or wherever the library is stored.

Comment: If your find command didn't return any results then you need to install and/or build the library.

Comment: I already have the library but still the same